# React Modal only using last item in a mapped set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble in a small application I'm building using React where I'm creating a node tree consisting of a root node, child nodes, and grandchild nodes. I can't seem to get a React Bootstrap modal accessing the correct id prop of a child node when I trigger the modal's show function.

In my page component, I'm mapping a set of children into the root node. As part of the child's rendering I'm passing in data from the parent to then populate a modal from which you can edit that child node's name. The code for the child node is below:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import "./Nodes.css"
    import GrandchildNode from "./GrandchildNode"
    import EditNameForm from '../Form/EditNameForm/index';
    import { MyModal } from '../Modals';

    class ChildNode extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        modalId: this.props.id
      }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      console.log(this.state.modalId)
    }

    render() {
      //console.log(this.state)
      let grandchildren = true;
      if (this.props.grandchildren.length === 0) {
        grandchildren = false
      }

    return (
      <div className='childWrapper'>
        <div className="childHeader">
          <div className="text" key={this.props.id}>{this.props.name}</div>
          <button className="edit" onClick={this.props.showNameEdit}>EDIT 
NAME</button>
          <button className="delete" onClick={() => 
    this.props.handleDelete(this.props.id)}>X</button>
        </div>
        <div className="childBody">
          {grandchildren ?
            this.props.grandchildren.map(item => {
              return <GrandchildNode key={item.id} name={item.name} parent= {item.parent} value={item.value}></GrandchildNode>
            }) : <div>No grandchildren to render</div>
          }
        </div>
        <MyModal
          show={this.props.showName}
          onHide={this.props.handleModalClose}
        >
          <EditNameForm
            errors={this.props.errorFields}
            handleInputChange={this.props.handleInputChange}
            name={this.props.name}
            newName={this.props.newName}
            handleModalClose={this.props.handleModalClose}
            handleFormSubmit={this.props.handleNameEdit}
            id={this.props.id}
          />
        </MyModal>
      </div>
    )
    }

    }

    export default ChildNode;
```

When open up the Modal for editing, it seems to render the Modal once for every child, and so the last child in the list ends up becoming the one which is edited - ex: Child1's id is "abcd", Child2's id is "efgh"; when I open the modal to edit Child1 I'm actually editing Child2 because Child2's id has been passed into the modal. I can confirm this via some code I added into my EditNameForm component:

```
class EditNameForm extends Component {
  state={
    id:this.props.id
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.state.id)
  }
```

The console.log(this.state.id) outputs something like this:

```
5c6311aa2b0593287832b0a2 EditNameForm.js:10 
5c63177d7124e5333886d91d EditNameForm.js:10
```

I've tried to understand what is happening here and I have some theories but they're hunches - anyone with more React experience, can you please help me understand a) what is happening here and b) how I can set it up so that the modal opens with the correct id prop?

Comment: you should show as parent component too

Answer (score 1):

You could use getDerivedStateFromProps function from [React Component Lifecycle](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-react-16-3-component-life-cycle-23129bc7a705) in you EditNameForm component.

Also i'm not sure it's actually props.id that you want to pass as a prop to your EditNameForm, because this one id is specific to the parent component and will not be changed on click of any child component. Also there is no function passed from the parent that would hint you actually change the parent state.

Some other hints that might help your development be smoother:

- Think to destructurate your props and state before using it

  ```
  const { errorFields, handleInputChange, name, newName, handleModalClose, handleNameEdit} = this.props;

  <EditNameForm
      errors={errorFields}
      handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
      name={name}
      newName={newName}
      handleModalClose={handleModalClose}
      handleFormSubmit={handleNameEdit}
      id={this.props.id}
  />
  ```

  - A component not nesting any child should be enclosed at once

`<GrandchildNode key={item.id} name={item.name} parent= {item.parent} value={item.value} />`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes!